# Should I destroy dynamically created Image.sprite?

Tags: unity, sprites, unity-ui, asset-management

Image sprite is created programmatically

```
_image.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, ...);
```

Should I destroy it before replacing with a new one?

P.S.
My question comes from these thoughts:
Unity components are destroyed when their scene objects are destroyed. Sprite is not a component, so it seems unclear to me if it will be destroyed somehow (when calling `Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets` or when the scene is unloading) in case it is disconnected from the image (replaced with another one).

Answer (score 0):

I found this post: https://answers.unity.com/questions/919594/how-to-destroy-spritecreate-leak.html

It seems to indicate that the more problematic part if the Texture being used:

"Textures are not garbage collected."

But I suppose if you're reusing Textures that's probably not an issue. If it is in fact an issue, it sounds like calling `Destroy` specifically is preferable to using `Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets`.

Comment: Yes, I destroy textures that are created programmatically, but what about Sprite itself? It probably doesn't take much space, still it's unclear if it is destroyed automatically or not.

Comment: Can you profile the app? I'm not too familiar with the Unity profiler, but I do know it has one built in. I'm guessing it would be pretty trivial to loop over some sprite creation code and see if the memory shoots up.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Unity profiler either, but I'll give it a try.